# Delete button giving me NameError in Rails+React app

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having a hard time getting the delete button to work on my Twitter-ish app. I get `500 (Internal Server Error)` on Chrome console and `` NameError (undefined local variable or method `tweet' for #<TweetsController:0x00007f91275b7448>): `` on my terminal when I hit a delete button.
That `console.log` in `onSubmitDelete(id)` is giving me the right selected tweet ID, therefore, my destroy action should be able to define which tweet I want to delete, shouldn't it? I don't know why my controller is giving me such an error. what can I do to fix it?

TweetsPage.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Tweets from './Tweets'

class TweetsPage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tweets: [],
      id: '',
    };
    this.onSubmitDelete = this.onSubmitDelete.bind(this);
  }
  loadTweetsFromServer() {
    const url = '/tweets/index.json';
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      cache: false,
      success: (data) => {
        this.setState({
          tweets: data
        });
      },
      error: (xhr, status, err) => {
        console.error(url, status, err.toString());
      },
    });
  }
  onSubmitDelete(id) {
    const url = '/tweets/destroy';
    console.log(id)
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'DELETE',
      cache: false,
      data: {
        id: id
      },
      success: (data) => {
        this.loadTweetsFromServer();
      },
      error: (xhr, status, err) => {
        console.error(url, status, err.toString());
      },
    });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadTweetsFromServer();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Tweets tweets={this.state.tweets} onDelete={this.onSubmitDelete} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TweetsPage;
```

tweets_controller.rb

```
def destroy
  tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
  tweet.destroy
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
delete 'tweets/destroy' => 'tweets#destroy'
```

Please let me know if you need to see my child components.

Comment: I'm pretty sure in your 'destroy', it should be `Tweet.find(params[:id])` without the `id:`. At least, the version of rails I use is like that. That might be causing an error.

Comment: You are right, I was mixed up with ```find``` & ```find_by``` and I just fixed it. However, it's still giving me the same error for some reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't mention but I was using Docker for Mac, so I restarted my container and it worked fine with no code changes. Silly.